# How do I access URL parameter after i've routed my express app to another file?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, node-modules, web-development-server

My main express server is called app.js in Node.js.

```
app.use("/login", require(./routes/login));
app.use("/:id", require("./routes/users"));
```

When I try to access the URL parameter, it returns undefined.

I tried logging req.params:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`Current Ornament Status and Data for ${req.params}`);
});

module.exports = router;
```

It gives me an empty array.

I suppose that it the parameter is inaccessible in another file after routing. Could you suggest a workaround?

Comment: You can access the params given as prefix of routes declaration. Short answer...

Comment: Hey, welcome to the community! I don't have an answer. But for the future, please use code snippets instead of screenshots.

Comment: please add the code snippets , so that we can have a proper  look on it and help you.

Comment: you have to pass req.parmas to functions in other files.

Comment: Code Snippets added, thanks to @almarc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing some fundamental bits about express.js routing for this to make sense.

The requires line means it is loading another piece of code. So you need to show us that too.

The :id thing requires a longer explanation.

Let's say I want the server to process the URL /finduser/23

Where 23 can vary, could be just about any number. I am NOT going to write 99 different versions of router.get, right?

```
router.get("/finduser/1",...
router.get("/finduser/2",...
router.get("/finduser/3",...
```

No, what we do is turn that into a parameter

```
router.get("/finduser/:id",...
```

Then whatever number we pass turns into req.params.id, assume router passes req,res

EX: If we pass URL /finderuser/15, then req.params.id = 15

If you just pass /finduser then req.params.id gets NOTHING.

Full details are available here
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters

Your example:

```
router.get('/dashboard', (req, res)
```

Doesn't have ANY parameters. so req.params.id has nothing.